# PhantomJS can't load correctly web page

Tags: python, windows, selenium, phantomjs, headless

I'm currently trying to scrape a web page with PhantomJS and Selenium (python 2.7.9 on Windows 7) but PhantomJS fail to load correctly the web page. If I use Firefox as webdriver I have no problem to see the page as I want. 
At first I thought it was a javascript problem (page-side) since with save_screenshot I could see what normally the page shows when javascript is disabled, but if I disable javascript the page show me correctly that "Javascript must be enabled", so it is not a js problem. Maybe some delay would help? I've also tried to put a time.sleep(up to 180 sec) but nothing.
Source code is below.

Any suggestion?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



import time



cap = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS
cap["phantomjs.page.settings.javascriptEnabled"] = True
#options = Options()
#options.headless = True
timeout = 30

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=tslv1.0'])

driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
driver.implicitly_wait(60)
#WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
#executable_path="C:\\userdata\\giom\\Py_exercises\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe"
driver.get("https://account.booking.com/register?op_token=EgVvYXV0aCJ7ChQ2Wjcyb0hPZDM2Tm43emszcGlyaBIJYXV0aG9yaXplGhpodHRwczovL2FkbWluLmJvb2tpbmcuY29tLyo2eyJwYWdlIjoiL3JlZGlyZWN0LXRvLWpvaW5hcHAtbHA_bGFuZz1pdCZhaWQ9MTE4NzM2MCJ9QgRjb2RlKg4QAToAQgBY5dGK8gVgAQ")
#driver.get('https://join.booking.com/category/index.html?label=continue&token=36094c4799610d5826138ec328f43b044b027cbb')
#result_loading = driver.onLoadFinished()
#print result_loading



html = driver.page_source
#print html.encode("utf-8")



driver.save_screenshot("C:\userdata\giom\Py_exercises\sample.png")

driver.close() 

#driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='root']")
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='login_name_register']")
```

Comment: First of all, would be good if you provided some more details so we can reproduce the problem.
Second PhantomJS stopped being developed since 2018, so it's better to use Firefox or Chrome in headless mode

Comment: Sure what do you need to know? I'm using python 2.7.9, selenium latest version and also lates version of phantomjs.

Comment: Well you could start with providing some code and the site you try to scrape. There might be a lot of reasons why site behaves in that way

Comment: I've just added it to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more information about your usecase would have helped to analyze your issue. However, on [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) **v3.141.0** and [phantomjs](/questions/tagged/phantomjs) **v2.1.1.0** here is the execution result:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\phantomjs.exe', service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=tslv1.0'])
  driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
  driver.get("https://account.booking.com/register?op_token=EgVvYXV0aCJ7ChQ2Wjcyb0hPZDM2Tm43emszcGlyaBIJYXV0aG9yaXplGhpodHRwczovL2FkbWluLmJvb2tpbmcuY29tLyo2eyJwYWdlIjoiL3JlZGlyZWN0LXRvLWpvaW5hcHAtbHA_bGFuZz1pdCZhaWQ9MTE4NzM2MCJ9QgRjb2RlKg4QAToAQgBY5dGK8gVgAQ")
  print(driver.page_source)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py:49: UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead
    warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless '
  <!DOCTYPE html><html class="js" lang="en-us"><head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script nonce="dmA0wdY6a4DdToc" src="https://account.booking.com/error_catcher"></script>
  <script nonce="dmA0wdY6a4DdToc">(function(H){H.className=H.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js')})(document.documentElement)</script>
  <title>Booking.com Account</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="referrer" content="origin-when-cross-origin">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  .
  .
  .
  <script nonce="dmA0wdY6a4DdToc"> (function() { var list = []; list.push({"private":{"account_oauth_small_print_footer":"By clicking \"{btn_label}\" you authorize {service_name} to use your {b_companyname} account info according to {service_name} {start_link}Terms of service{end_link}.","account_sign_in_no_venue_input":"Enter your venue name","account_tfa_email_heading":"Two Factor Authentication","account_oauth_review_includes":"Includes:","account_sign_in_menu_create_account":"Create your account","account_create_phone_label":"Phone number","iam_ext_signin_subtitle":"Continue to view the credit card details. ","account_tfa_pulse_verification_header":"Pulse verification code","sal_provider_account_create_consent_continue":"Continue","iam_ext_password_expired_header":"Your password has expired","iam_ap_dropdown_menu_desc":"Useful links menu","account_oauth_service_would_like_to_access":"{start_bold}{service_name}{end_bold} wants to access:","extranet_cant_2fa_no_access_to_phone":"The phone number is correct, but nobody has access to it","account_oauth_service_would_like_to_access_your":"{service_name} wants to access your:","account_modal_forgot_your_password_inform":"No problem – want to reset your password?","account_terms_privacy_footer":"By signing in or creating an account, you agree with our {start_link1}Terms & Conditions{end_link1} and {start_link2}Privacy Statement{end_link2}","account_create_password_different_pw_error":"The passwords you entered didn't match – try again","account_create_account_inform":"Create an account to use {b_companyname} services easily.","account_sign_in_menu_forgot_username":"Forgot your email address?","oauth_scope_title_photo":"Photo","ext_onboarding_create_password_bad_password":"Passwords can't be reused, need to be at least 8 characters long (containing both numbers and letters), and shouldn't use a predictable pattern, word, or phrase.","account_copyright":"Copyright (2006-{year}) – Booking.com™ ","account_recover_no_input":"Enter your email address","oauth_scope_title_birth_date":"Date of birth","account_sign_in_grab":"Sign in with Grab","oauth_scope_title_payment_details":"Payment details","iam_ap_sign_in_link":"Already have an account? {start_link}Sign in{end_link}","account_create_password_phone_inform":"Choose a password for your {b_companyname} account connected to {phone}.","account_social_error_no_email":"We haven't received your email – please try again.","account_signin_add_password_header":"Create a password","account_sign_in_apple":"Sign in with Apple","account_sign_in_no_such_username":"There's no account associated with this username. {start_link}Create an account{end_link} to access our services","account_validation_sms_code_invalid":"Verification code needs to contain 6 digits","account_sign_in_create_header":"Don't have an account yet?","account_modal_forgot_your_password_header":"Forgot your password?","account_create_account_fb":"Register with Facebook","account_create_account_wechat":"Register with WeChat","account_recover_options_header":"Having trouble signing in?","account_tfa_menu_item_other":"Other options","account_create_account_next_cta":"Next","account_sign_in_china_auth_low_header":"Welcome back","account_create_phone_confirm_header":"Phone number verification","account_create_account_user_found":"You already have a {b_companyname} account registered to this email: {email}. You can {start_link}sign in here{end_link}.","account_reset_password_confirm_lbl":"Confirm password","account_confirmation_token_expired":"The verification link has expired – please try again.","account_tfa_customer_service_option_inform":"Call your local customer service at the number listed {start_link}here{end_link} and give us the PIN you see on the screen. The customer service agent will give you a new verification code to enter below.","ext_admin_button_register":"Register","account_reset_password_inform_extranet":"Pick a new password for your {b_companyname} account. It should not contain your property ID or username.","oauth_scope_title_address":"Address","account_terms_conditions":"Terms & conditions","account_sign_in_create_header_ext":"Add your property to {b_companyname}","account_tfa_pulse_verification_help_cta":"Where is the code?","account_tfa_loading":"Loading...","account_phone_verification_signin_cta":"Verify and sign in","account_create_password_short_pw_error":"Your password needs to be at least 8 characters long","account_tfa_verification_methods_header":"Verification method","account_sign_in_no_input":"Enter your email address","account_incorrect_phone":"Enter the phone number linked to your account","account_sign_in_password_inform":"Enter your {b_companyname} password for {start bold}{email_address}{end bold}.","account_sign_in_auth_low_password_header_with_name":"Welcome back, {name}","account_tfa_verification_method_sms":"Text message (SMS)","account_verify_resend_email_cta":"Resend email","account_create_surname_label":"Last name","account_recover_back_to_sign_in":"Back to sign-in","account_locked_inform":"We temporarily locked your account for security reasons. To unlock your account, click \"Resend email\" below and we'll email you a link to reset your password.","account_sign_in_inform":"You can sign in using your {b_companyname} account to access our services.","iam_ext_password_too_small_or_too_big":"Password must be between 8 and 72 characters long","account_reset_password_sign_in_cta":"Sign in","account_sign_in_china_auth_low_cta":"Sign in","account_validation_sms_code_empty":"Enter a verification code","account_tfa_recovery_error_incorrect_phone":"This phone number doesn't match the one in our records – please try again.","account_tabs_phone_lbl":"Mobile number","account_oauth_review_allow_service_to_access":"Allow {start_bold}{service_name}{end_bold} to access:","account_sign_in_auth_low_password_inform":"Looks like you've been away for a while. Please enter your {b_companyname} password for {start_bold}{email_address}{end_bold}. {start_link}Not you?{end_link}","language_exception_account_tfa_timer_1":"This message should arrive in {tfa_timer} second.","account_tfa_timer":"This message should arrive in {tfa_timer} seconds.","account_sign_in_invalid_phone":"Make sure the phone number you entered is correct.","account_validation_password_too_short":"Your new password has to be at least 8 characters long","extranet_cant_2fa_phone_is_incorrect":"The phone number is incorrect, but I can't log in to update it\n","account_recover_go_to_sign_in":"Go to sign-in","iam_ap_signup_link":"Don't have an account yet? {start_link}Sign up{end_link}","account_recover_contact_support_inform":"Unfortunately, we're unable to help you retrieve your username – please contact your local support team.","accounts_lb_session_timedout_inactivity":"Your session timed out due to inactivity. Reenter your password to continue. ","account_error_invalid_username_password_attempt":"The username and password entered don't match – please try again. After {num} attempts, your account will be locked. Forgot your password? Click {start_link}here to reset it{end_link}.","account_error_already_confirmed":"Your account was already verified.","account_create_account_china_header":"Create your account","asi_scalability_partner_login_password_flow_show_password":"Show password","oauth_scope_title_email":"Email address","close":"Close","account_tfa_error_incorrect_code":"This verification code is incorrect – please try again. ","web_ge_week_block_sub_header_sign_in":"You'll get 7 days of Genius travel rewards when you sign in","account_create_title_label_mr":"Mr.","account_sign_in_invalid_email":"Make sure the email address you entered is correct. ","account_reset_password_password_lbl":"New {b_companyname} password","iam_ap_joinapp_header":"Sign up","account_signin_add_password_btn":"Create password and sign in","account_sign_in_china_cta":"Sign in","account_menu_back":"Back","account_validation_name":"Enter your full name and title","account_validation_phone_code_empty":"Enter a verification code","auth_next_step_error_wrong_verification_code":"Enter a valid verification code","loc_social_connect_google_sign_in":"Sign in with Google","account_portal_back_btn_label":"Return to the previous page","account_phone_verification_inform":"You can sign in by verifying your number {start_strong}{phone}{end_strong} through a text.","account_create_account_naver":"Register with Naver","account_create_password_repeat_no_pw_error":"Confirm your password","account_modal_forgot_your_password_cta_yes":"Yes, help me","account_error_password_attempt_when_disabled":"Password not reset","account_add_backup_option_inform":"Set a password so you can still sign in when you don't have access to your phone.","iam_ext_previous_password_used":"Looks like this password was recently updated.","iam_password_policy_indicator_extranet":"Your password should be at least {start_style_one}eight characters{end_style_one} long and contain both {start_style_two}letters{end_style_two} and {start_style_three}numbers{end_style_three}.","account_tfa_select_phone_header":"Select phone number","account_create_account_email_or_phone_lbl":"Email or phone","account_oauth_connect_as":"as: {username}","account_sign_in_china_add_phone_cta":"Verify now","account_signin_method_email":"Sign in with email","account_sign_in_no_such_venue_username":"There's no account associated with this venue/username","account_sign_in_china_add_phone_header":"Verify mobile number","extranet_cant_2fa_phone_not_private":"The phone number is correct, but someone else has access to it","account_tfa_header":"Two Factor Authentication","account_sign_in_china_add_phone_inform":"Verify your mobile number. This will help us confirm your identity and protect your account.","account_sign_in_naver":"Sign in with Naver","account_signin_verify_email_btn":"Send email verification link","iam_ext_signin_title":"Sign in ","we_use_cookies":"This website uses cookies. Click {startlink}here{endlink} for more information.","account_create_property_ext":"Create account","account_tfa_recovery_next_cta":"Next","social_connect_title_apple":"Apple","account_sign_in_auth_low_password_header":"Welcome back","account_sign_in_no_username_input":"Enter your username","accounts_make_changes_with_bno_and_pin":"Make changes to a booking with your {start_link}confirmation number and PIN{end_link}","account_oauth_cancel":"Cancel","account_rights_reserved":"All rights reserved","oauth_scope_title_location":"Location","account_sign_in_china_inform":"Sign in using your {b_companyname} account to access our services.","account_sign_in_email_lbl":"Email","account_tfa_options_submit_cta":"Verify now","account_recover_confirm_email_cta":"Confirm","lxp_copy_bp_account_lightbox_header_password_cta":"Create my password","iam_ext_reassurance":"We're currently improving the way you sign in to the Extranet","iam_ext_customer_service_pin":"Provide {b_companyname} with this PIN:","account_recover_forgot_username":"Forgot your username?","account_tfa_recovery_header":"Confirm phone number","account_validation_phone_empty":"Enter a phone number","account_create_personal_details_header":"Contact details","social_connect_title_grab":"Grab","account_recover_invalid_email":"Double-check your email address is correct","account_sign_in_password_forgot":"Forgot your password?","account_tfa_pulse_help_inform":"Find your verification code in Pulse by following these steps:","account_create_account_or":"or","account_sign_in_china_wrong_password":"Incorrect password – try again.","ugc_error_message_locked_account":"To protect you, we've locked your account after multiple incorrect password entries. Please wait or {start_link}reset your password{end_link} to unlock.","account_oauth_allow_access":"Allow access","account_create_title_label":"Title","account_tfa_verification_code_sent_timer":"The verification code should arrive in {tfa_timer} seconds","account_phone_login_reset_pw_sms":"{b_companyname} password reset link: {url}","account_verify_maybe_later_cta":"I'll do this later","account_signin_methods_inform":"Select a login method","account_create_account_header":"Create your account","ext_login_pw_fail_link":"The login name and password you entered don't match – please try again. After {num} attempts, you'll be locked out of your account. You can reset your password by clicking, {start_link}\"Forget your password?\"{end_link}.","account_sign_in_google":"Sign in with Google","account_tfa_pulse_help_header":"Finding your verification code","language_exception_account_tfa_verification_code_sent_mini_timer_1":"{tfa_timer}s","account_sign_in_fb":"Sign in with Facebook","iam_password_policy_indicator_styling":"Your password needs to have {start_style_one}at least one number{end_style_one} and a {start_style_two}minimum of eight characters{end_style_two}.","account_disabled_header":"Account disabled","account_sign_in_china_auth_low_inform":"To sign in, you need to verify your phone number. We sent a code to {start_strong}{phone}{end_strong}. Enter it below to continue. {start_link}Not your number?{end_link}","account_tfa_select_phone_help_cta":"Unable to verify?","fe_index_list_property_persuasion_text":"Rent out your place on {b_companyname}","account_create_account_phone_found":"You already have a {b_companyname} account registered to this phone: {phone}. You can {start_link}sign in here{end_link}.","language_exception_account_error_invalid_username_password_attempt_1":"The username and password entered don't match – please try again. After {num} attempt, your account will be locked. Forgot your password? Click {start_link}here to reset it{end_link}.","account_tfa_email_context":"We emailed you a temporary verification code that will allow you to access your account.","account_create_account_sign_in_cta":"Sign in","account_signin_method_wechat":"Sign in with WeChat","account_oauth_review_save_cta":"Save","account_input_email_lbl":"Email","account_tfa_verification_code_lbl":"Verification code","account_sign_in_create_inform":"Create an account to use {b_companyname} services easily.","account_sign_in_china_header":"Sign in","account_menu_close":"Close","account_sign_in_inform_ext":"Access the Extranet to manage your property, continue registration or list a new property.","ext_admin_login_page_sign_in_to_manage":"Sign in to manage your property","account_locked_inform_email":"To unlock your account, request an email with a link to reset your password.","account_error_invalid_username_password":"The username and password combination entered doesn't match.","account_tfa_verification_methods_inform":"Select a verification method to complete the sign-in process.","account_tfa_pulse_verification_inform":"To complete your sign-in, open the Pulse app to find your verification code. If you can't verify it, look at these {start_link}other options{end_link}","account_reset_password_header":"Create new password","iam_ext_help_links_old":"Questions about your property or the Extranet? Check out {start_link1}Partner Help{end_link1} or ask another partner on the {start_link2}Partner Forum{end_link2}.","account_create_existing_user_found":"You already have an account registered with this email: {email}. You can {start_link}sign in{end_link} directly.","account_recover_email_lbl":"Email address","account_signin_verify_email_inform":"You're trying to sign in to an account that doesn't have a password. To sign in, verify your email.","account_disabled_inform_cta":"Contact support","social_connect_title_opentable":"OpenTable","account_sign_in_no_such_user":"Looks like there isn't an account associated with this email address. You can {start_link}create an account{end_link} to access our services.","iam_ext_password_not_alphanumeric":"Password must contain a combination of letters and numbers","account_sign_in_password_menu_forgot_pw":"Forgot your password? Reset it here","account_locked_inform_phone":"To unlock your account, request a text with a link to reset your password.","account_tfa_resend_sms":"Resend code","iam_ext_password_not_allowed":"Passwords shouldn't contain easy-to-guess character strings (e.g. your username, hotel ID, email, etc.)","account_sign_in_wechat":"Sign in with WeChat","account_signin_methods_header":"Sign in","account_recover_phone_confirmation_inform":"We just sent a text message with a link to reset your password to {start_bold}{user_name}{end_bold}.","account_error_invalid_email_password":"The email and password combination entered doesn't match.","account_create_account_email_lbl":"Email","account_tfa_customer_service_option_header":"Contact customer service","account_locked_inform_new":"We've locked your {b_companyname} account for security purposes.","account_recover_phone_inform":"Just confirm your phone number, then we'll send you a link to reset your password.","account_modal_forgot_your_password_cta_no":"No, try again","bp_account_lightbox_header_password_2":"Create a password so you can securely manage this booking","account_tfa_recovery_error_no_phone":"Please enter a phone number","account_tfa_pulse_verification_help_back_cta":"Back to verification","account_input_phone_lbl":"Phone","settings_page_error_message":"Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again.","account_validation_new_password_empty":"Please enter your new password","account_signin_verification_sent_inform":"We sent a link to verify your email to {start_strong}{user_name}{end_strong}. Follow the link in the email to continue.","asi_scalability_partner_login_password_flow_hide_password":"Hide password","account_settings_label_language":"Language","account_sign_in_password_header":"Sign in","account_validation_sms_phone_invalid":"Not a valid phone number","account_create_password_header":"Create password","account_sign_in_next_cta":"Next","account_sign_in_or":"or","account_create_phone_confirm_inform":"A text message with a 6-digit verification code was sent to your phone for verification.","account_recover_confirmation_inform":"We just emailed a link to reset your password to {start_bold}{user_name}{end_bold}.","account_tfa_select_phone_for_sms_inform":"Select a phone number to receive your verification code in a text message (SMS)","account_create_account_china_inform":"Create an account to use {b_companyname} services.","account_locked_send_email_cta":"Unlock with email","account_sign_in_email_or_phone_lbl":"Email or phone","web_ge_week_block_promo_message_all_users":"Genius is {b_companyname}'s loyalty program","account_sign_in_china_phone_not_found":"There's no account registered with this number. {start_link}Create an account{end_link} to access our services.","account_tfa_email_lbl":"Verification code","account_create_title_label_ms":"Ms.","account_sign_in_create_inform_ext":"Create a partner account to list and manage your property.","account_sign_in_attractions_no_account_error":"There isn't an account connected to this username. {start_link}Create an account{end_link} to access our services.","extranet_cant_2fa_because_no_call_sms":"The phone number is correct, but I didn't receive a call/text message","account_cookies_close":"Close","account_sign_in_header_new":"Sign in","account_reset_password_cta":"Set new password","account_tfa_menu_item_resend":"Resend code","account_recover_options_inform":"We're here to help. Below are some options to help you get back on track.","account_contact_support_cta":"Contact support","account_sign_in_password_validation_no_pw":"Enter your {b_companyname} password","language_exception_account_tfa_verification_code_sent_mini_timer_0":"{tfa_timer}s","account_social_email_inform":"Enter your email to continue","account_verify_inform_activation":"To confirm your account, follow the link in the email we just sent.","account_list_your_property":"List Your Property","account_oauth_menu_item_sign_out":"Sign out","account_tabs_email_lbl":"Email address","oauth_scope_title_dob":"Date of birth","account_forgot_username":"Forgot your username?","account_settings_security_error_wrong_verification_code":"Enter a valid verification code","account_tfa_ios_verification_device":"iOS devices","social_connect_title_google":"Google","account_recover_heading":"Forgot your password?\n\n","iam_ext_password_expired_inform":"To keep your account secure, you'll need to reset your password. We sent a reset link to {start_bold}{email}{end_bold}.","ext_admin_button_register_another_property":"Register another property","account_create_title_label_mrs":"Mrs.","account_tfa_options_back_cta":"Back to verification","partner_fraud_verification_portal_attempts_header":"Sorry, too many attempts","web_ge_week_block_sub_header_create_account":"You'll get 7 days of Genius travel rewards when you create an account","account_signin_method_phone":"Sign in with phone number","account_create_account_get_started_cta":"Get started","iam_ap_joinapp_inform":"Create an account to list and manage your property.","account_tfa_verification_method_pulse":"Pulse app","login_error_wrong":"Incorrect email address or password. Please try again.","ext_admin_login_name":"Login name","account_tfa_verification_method_call":"Phone call","account_please_verify_header":"Verify your account","account_please_verify_inform":"In order to access {start_bold}{service_name}{end_bold} you have to verify your {b_companyname} account.","account_tfa_andorid_device":"Android devices","account_sign_in_china_auth_low_inform_v2":"Sign in by verifying your number {start_strong}{phone}{end_strong} by text. {start_link}Not your number?{end_link}","language_exception_account_tfa_email_timer_1":"This email should arrive in {tfa_timer} second.","account_signin_verify_email_header":"Verify your email","social_connect_title_naver":"Naver","account_validation_phone_acc_exists":"You already have an account registered with this number. Continue with verification to sign in.","account_tfa_recovery_phone_lbl":"Phone number","account_tfa_verification_code_sent_inform":"We sent a verification code to your phone: {start_bold}{phone_number}{end_bold}. If you still can't verify it, review these {start_link}other options{end_link}","account_sign_in_password_validation_combo":"The email and password combination you entered doesn't match.","account_verify_inform":"We sent an email with a verification link to {start_bold}{email}{end_bold}.","account_create_password_create_cta":"Create account","account_recover_confirmation_header":"Check your inbox","account_tfa_verification_code_call_timer":"You should get a phone call soon","account_locked_header":"Account locked","account_tfa_verification_code_andorid":"Find code in Pulse for Android","account_confirmation_problem":"Something went wrong","account_oauth_edit_information":"Manage permissions","account_tfa_select_phone_cta":"Call now","account_phone_verification_header":"Verify your number","account_tfa_menu_item_close":"Close","account_locked_resend_email_cta":"Resend email","account_reset_password_confirmed_header":"New password confirmed","account_connect_social_password_header":"Confirm your password","oauth_scope_title_genius":"Genius status","bba_register_b4b_2":"Interested in {start_link}{b_companyname} for Business?{end_link}","account_tfa_an_sms_sent":"We sent a verification code to your phone. Please enter this code in the box below.  If you can't use the verification code, check out these {start_link}other options{end_link}.","account_create_password_pw_lbl":"Create password","account_sign_in_cta":"Sign in","iam_ext_partner_hep_centre_link":"Have any questions about your property or the Extranet? Check out {start_link}Partner Help{end_link} to learn more.","account_sign_in_password_cta":"Sign in","account_tfa_verification_code_call_inform":"Enter the verification code provided to you by {b_companyname}. If you can't verify it, review these {start_link}other options{end_link}","language_exception_account_tfa_verification_code_sent_timer_1":"The verification code should arrive in {tfa_timer} second","account_create_first_name_label":"First name","account_business_bookers":"Interested in {start_link}{b_companyname} for Business?{end_link}","account_recover_contact_support_header":"Contact local support team","account_tfa_customer_service_option2_inform":"Keep in mind that for security reasons we can only authorize logins verified by a call/text message. If you can't use any of your saved phone numbers right now, try waiting until you can use them. If you have an urgent issue but don't have access to these phone numbers, {start_link}contact us here{end_link}.","account_recover_inform":"Just confirm your email, then we'll send you a link to reset your password","account_validation_phone_code_invalid":"Verification code needs to contain 6 digits","oauth_scope_title_phone":"Phone number","account_create_account_google":"Register with Google","account_create_password_repeat_pw_lbl":"Confirm password","account_email_confirmed_thanks":"Thanks for confirming your email address.","account_tfa_error_no_code":"Please provide a verification code","account_oauth_not_you":"Not you?","account_tfa_code_lbl":"Verification code","account_tfa_menu_item_back":"Back","account_signin_password_header":"Sign in with password","account_signin_add_password_inform":"Create a password for your account to avoid this later.","iam_a11y_current_language_aria_label":"Select your language. Your current language is {/language_options/[language]/name}","account_oauth_service_would_like_to_access_no_sharing":"None of your {b_companyname} account info will be shared with {service_name}","account_locked_send_sms_cta":"Unlock with text message","language_exception_ext_login_pw_fail_link_1":"The login name and password you entered don't match – please try again. After {num} attempt, you'll be locked out of your account. You can reset your password by clicking, {start_link}\"Forget your password?\"{end_link}.","account_tfa_email_timer":"This email should arrive in {tfa_timer} seconds.","account_reset_password_confirmed_inform":"Welcome back! Your new password was confirmed","iam_ap_dropdown_menu_btn_label":"Useful links","account_disabled_inform":"For security reasons, this {b_companyname} account belonging to {user_name} was disabled from accessing our products and services.","account_signin_continue_with_wechat":"Continue with WeChat","account_tfa_select_phone_sms_cta":"Send verification code","account_tfa_send_sms":"Send code","social_connect_title_facebook":"Facebook","account_oauth_connect_to":"Connect to {start_bold}{service_name}{end_bold}","account_tfa_options_header":"Reasons for verification issues","web_ge_week_block_header_all_users":"It's Genius Week!","account_validation_sms_phone_empty":"Enter a phone number","account_validation_last_name_empty":"Enter your last name","account_locked_incorrect_password_limit":"We temporarily locked your account because you entered an incorrect password several times. To unlock your account, click \"Resend email\" below and we'll email you a link to reset your password.","sal_provider_account_create_consent_header":"You're about to sign in to {b_companyname} 
  .
  .
  .
  <iframe name="_hjRemoteVarsFrame" title="_hjRemoteVarsFrame" id="_hjRemoteVarsFrame" src="https://vars.hotjar.com/box-469cf41adb11dc78be68c1ae7f9457a4.html" style="display: none !important; width: 1px !important; height: 1px !important; opacity: 0 !important; pointer-events: none !important;"></iframe><div id="ads"></div></body></html>
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I also can see source code of web page, but when I take a screenshot, it is empty. Can you try to take one and tell me what do you see?

Comment: @giom `screenshot` wasn't your question but `html = driver.page_source` was your question. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement. Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: I talk about taking screenshot inside description of my problem. In any case I will open another question.